# Running code for the first element in jQuery each() loop that satisfies a condition

Tags: jquery, each

I know how to run code for first element found in each() loop:

```
$('.selector').each(function(i, el){
    if ( i === 0) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

But how to run code for first element *satisfying a certain condition* in the each() loop?

Something like this:

```
$('.selector').each(function(i, el){
    if ( first element meeting the condition ) {
        // do A
    }
    elseif ( next elements meeting the condition ) {
        // do B
    }
    else {
        // do C
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the condition?

Comment: Once you've matched the selector the first time, you can break out of the each() by doing `return false`. Or, if you need to keep going, declare a boolean outside of the each() and set it to true inside the loop when the condition is satisfied. Use the boolean as part of the condition that is checked.

Comment: Josh Crozier: is the selector's class equal to a variable? If yes then do X, if not then do Y. And this must apply only for first element found. The next ones is another story.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a variable *outside* of the loop and use that to determine whether the condition has been satisfied. Once the condition is satisfied, change the variable to prevent it from being executed again.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9eg9r0r/)

```
(function () {
    var conditionSatisfied = false;
    $('.selector').each(function (i, el) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('foo') && !conditionSatisfied) {
            conditionSatisfied = true;
            // ..
        } else {
            // ..
        }
    });
})();
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may not actually need a loop. You could just select the element directly. For instance, you could select the `.selector` element with class `.foo`, and use either `:first`/`.first()` in order to select the first matching element.

```
$('.selector.foo').first();
```

```
$('.selector.foo:first');
```

Comment: Thx but it's the first element meeting the condition, not necessarily the first element of the set

Comment: @drake035 Oh, okay. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do something to the first element that has some text for example just do `if (el.text() == 'something')`  and then call `return` inside the condition to stop